# If I wanted to attach additional data to an element for JS retrieval

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a `<select>` list of products that I generate with PHP. I would like to store each product's weight in each `<option>` element somehow so that I can retrieve it later with Javascript.

I would like to print the data in the element (as opposed to adding it with Javascript). Something like this.

```
<option value="foo" weight="25">bar</option>
```

This seems to work with IE, but not Firefox and others.

I want to avoid storing a JSON string in the value property if possible. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `data-` attributes and retrieve their values with [jquery.data()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) function:

```
<option value="foo" data-weight="25">bar</option>

---
JS:

alert($('your option').data('weight')); 
==> 25
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an [HTML5 `data-*`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/elements.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-attributes) attribute:

```
<option value="foo" data-weight="25">bar</option>
```